# how to recuperate result of select query in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, oracle, select

this is my code, it wont recuperate the result of select query in my list :

```
Imports Oracle.DataAccess.Client

Public Class ListForm

Private Sub ListForm_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim cn As OracleConnection
    cn = New OracleConnection("User ID=admin;password=admin;")
    Dim cmd As New OracleCommand()
    cmd.Connection = cn
    cn.Open()
    cmd.CommandText = "select name from system.Table"
    Dim dr As OracleDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    While dr.Read()
        List.Items.Add(dr.GetValue(0))
    End While
    dr.Close()
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: to give more details, the program works with no exceptions but the list stays empty !

Answer (score 1):

Put a breakpoint inside the loop and see how many times the list.items.add method is called. If zero, check the database query. If it is executed, check the value of dr.GetValue(0). If it's normal, you may need to refresh the list.

Comment: the loop doesn't executed any time, and my DB is correct, when i execute "select name from system.Table;" directly in oracle it gives 2 lines ..